# how to add icons in actionbar when its setSupportActionBar

Tags: android

I have the below code that set the toolbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //downloadImage();
}
```

should I add this code ?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

What I want to have icons in the toolbar action bar how to do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you should add

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
 //and this to handle actions
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

to add icons ,go to main.xml under menu directory and add

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I should return         return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
?

Comment: You should call super first and return true.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I add this and it worked .. it is correct right ? 

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

    }

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need that code. So you want to have a xml file, you can call it "main_menu.xml"

Then add this code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mainMenu2"
        android:icon="@drawable/main_menu"  // replace main_menu with your drawable
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:title="Main Menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" /> />

</menu>
```

Just make sure you put your drawable here "android:icon=**add drawable**" and it would appear. Good luck and have fun!